# Java: JOption pane element listing

Tags: java, arrays, swing, joptionpane

How can you display multiple elements of an array in JOption pane without an individual window for each element? The following code will output a single window for each element of inputDie1[x], how can I list them? i.e. 5, 1, 6, 1, 2 in one window.

```
   for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
   {
       randomValue1 = ((int)(Math.random() * 100) % HIGHEST_DIE_VALUE 
          + LOWEST_DIE_VALUE);
                inputDie1[x].setValue1(randomValue1);

       randomValue2 = ((int)(Math.random() * 100) % HIGHEST_DIE_VALUE 
          + LOWEST_DIE_VALUE);
                inputDie2[x].setValue2(randomValue2);

       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, inputDie1[x].getValue1());
   }
```

after concatenation

```
           for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
           {v1 = inputDie1[x].getValue1();}

           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, v1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is rather than putting this `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, inputDie1[x].getValue1());` line in the loop, Make a string and concatenate every time in the loop and finally when you get out of the loop. Show this string in the JOptionPane Message Dialog

Comment: @ewbrowning Please accept(if it satisfied your needs) the answer and upvote it(if you like my answer)

Comment: I'm working on it right now and have concatenated each value and assigned them to int v1. Upon trying to sys out, my compiler is telling me that v1 has not been initialized. Setting it to 0 initially doesn't work, do you have any more suggestions?

Comment: @ewbrowning Could you put all of your new code, because I am not able to debug it like this